# What's a program for creating a VERY simple offline android app with low coding requirement?

Tags: windows, gratis, android, software-development, offline

This might come off as a weird or stupid question but please bear with me

In short, my concern is making an app that lets me design very simple animations and can read and display real-time and date, for completely personal use.

I have at my disposal a windows 10 PC and an Android 11 Oppo Reno 3, so this probably means I need a windows program that lets me design very simple apps to be used on an android device offline.

To convey the general idea, the android application oughta have:

1- a start up screen with a button

2- has multiple tabs like a browser with some images inside of each tab

3- can display the current time and date in a specific location on top of the image (which is inside one of the taps)

The app will be a very simple offline one with no need for any real security protocols or any connections to any databases.

The images to be display are ones I can make in gimp or photoshop as .png or such so that's not a problem.

It is **important** that the programs needed to create the app are free or open source and are low-code/no-code.

Something really as simple as Pixate but can display real time and date.

Comment: is any other information required?